# error with running multiple thread with C example

Tags: c, multithreading, compiler-errors, pthreads

I have found an example of multi thread programming which help to determine the prime numbers for a given integar n.it will also take number of thread as a input from the user.But the problem is when i try to execute it give me some errors which very hard to solve.Can anyone help?I am newbies at coding so any type of help and advice will be greatly appreciated.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>  // required for threads usage

#define MAX_N 100000000
#define MAX_THREADS 25


int nthreads, n, prime[MAX_N+1], nextbase;  // next sieve multiplier to be used
// lock for the shared variable nextbase
pthread_mutex_t nextbaselock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
// ID structs for the threads
pthread_t id[MAX_THREADS];

// "crosses out" all odd multiples of k
void crossout(int k)
{  int i;
   for (i = 3; i*k <= n; i += 2)  {
      prime[i*k] = 0;
   }
}

// each thread runs this routine
void *worker(int tn)  // tn is the thread number (0,1,...)
{  int lim,base,
       work = 0;  // amount of work done by this thread
   // no need to check multipliers bigger than sqrt(n)
   lim = sqrt(n);
   do  {

      pthread_mutex_lock(&nextbaselock);
      base = nextbase;
      nextbase += 2;
      // unlock the lock
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&nextbaselock);
      if (base <= lim)  {
         // don't bother crossing out if base known composite
         if (prime[base])  {
            crossout(base);
            work++;  // log work done by this thread
         }
      }
      else return work; 
   } while (1);
}

main(int argc, char **argv)
{  int nprimes,  // number of primes found 
       i,work;
   n = atoi(argv[1]);
   nthreads = atoi(argv[2]);

   for (i = 3; i <= n; i++)  {
      if (i%2 == 0) prime[i] = 0;
      else prime[i] = 1;
   }
   nextbase = 3;
   // get threads started
   for (i = 0; i < nthreads; i++)  {

      pthread_create(&id[i],NULL,worker,i);
   }


   for (i = 0; i < nthreads; i++)  {

      pthread_join(id[i],&work);
      printf("%d values of base done\n",work);
   }


   nprimes = 1;
   for (i = 3; i <= n; i++)
      if (prime[i])  {
         nprimes++;
      }
   printf("the number of primes found was %d\n",nprimes);
}
```

I have the following error while compiling:

> ```
>  In function ‘worker’:
> Primes.c:67:12: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
>        else return work; 
>             ^
> Primes.c: In function ‘main’:
> Primes.c:88:7: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
>        pthread_create(&id[i],NULL,worker,i);
>        ^
> In file included from Primes.c:15:0:
> /usr/include/pthread.h:244:12: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void * (*)(int)’
>  extern int pthread_create (pthread_t *__restrict __newthread,
>             ^
> Primes.c:88:7: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘pthread_create’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
>        pthread_create(&id[i],NULL,worker,i);
>        ^
> In file included from Primes.c:15:0:
> /usr/include/pthread.h:244:12: note: expected ‘void * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘int’
> ```

Comment: Please specify more detailed which errors you get and what problems you have with solving these

Comment: If you are indeed a new coder, then multithreaded programs are *not* where you want to start.  Indeed, computing prime factorizations is entirely tricky enough for a newbie on its own, without bringing threads into it.  Moreover, you are likely to learn much more by writing your own programs than by copying others'.

Comment: @JohnBollinger can you suggest me some references where i can learn multi thread programming easily ?i googled but these references seems not so crystal clear..

Comment: @suhailmahmud, no.  Multithreaded programming is hard.  There are plenty of tutorials documentation, etc., but none can make it easy.  If you think you've found one that does, then it is oversimplifying.  In any case, requests for off-site resources are off-topic here.

Comment: @suhailmahmud - you need to learn all the basics first and learn to understand compiler errors and warnings before going into multi-threading. Just like school. You didn't learn Algebra in Grade 1. If they tried to teach you Geometry in Grade 2, it will just zoom and you won't understand a bit. One step at a time and someday you'll find yourself coding in MT.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys.but can anyone let me know where is the problem of the code?the Pthread_create function has a problem with one of it's parameter,showing incompatible pointer type.any help so i can fix it?

Comment: suggest making extensive use of the man pages for each of the functions your calling.

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans: 1) Please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* 2) Please use meaningful variable and parameter names: parameters like: `k` and variable like `n` carry no meaning.  A name should indicate either usage or content or (preferably) both.

Comment: the signature of a thread function is: `void * threadName( void *);`  Your thread function does not implement that signature.

Comment: in the main() function, never access any argv[] index beyond `argv[0]` without first checking the value contained in `argc` to assure the desired parameter(s) exist.  If the desired command line parameters were not entered by the user, then such access is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  If the proper number of command line parameters were not entered by the user, then call: `fprintf( stderr, " %s <list of parameters>\n", argv[0]);` followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Note: exit() and EXIT_FAILURE found in stdlib.h

Comment: the proper way to return from a thread is: pthread_exit( &status ); Note: the status variable should be in the file global space, not the thread stack

Comment: Suggest: get the program working correctly with out any threads, then introduce the complication of using threads

Answer (score -1):

using: `gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -std=gnu99 %f`

where `%f` is the name of the file being compiled

The compiler output the following messages.

I added some commentary for each message that should point you to how to fix the problem.

compiler warning message:

```
:28:14: warning: conversion to 'int' from 'double' may alter its' value [-Wconversion]

lim = sqrt(n);
```

The function: `sqrt()` returns a 'double' but 'lim' is declared a 'int'

Suggest:  cast the returned value to 'int'

```
lim = (int)sqrt(n);
```

compiler warning message:

```
:43:12: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [enbled by default]

else return work;
```

1. the return type from the `worker()` function is `void*`
2. always exit the `worker()` function by:

   pthread_exit( &work );

compiler warning message:

```
:24:18: warning: unused parameter 'tn' [-Wunused-parameter]
```

means the parameter 'tn' is not used. fix this by inserting in that function the line:

```
(void)tn;
```

compiler warning message:

```
47:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [enabled by default]
```

The signature of the main() function is not correct.  without using the environment parameter, (almost never used), there are only 2 valid main() signatures and one optional signature.

use the correct signature for what your program needs.

```
int main( void )
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) 
int main()  // optional signature
```

compiler warning message:

```
50:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'atoi' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

means the header file: `stdlib.h` has not been #include'd suggest inserting at top of file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

compiler warning message:

```
61:7: warning: passing argument 3 of 'pthread_create' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

means the third parameter to the function: `pthread_create()` was not a void pointer.  suggest:

```
pthread_create(&id[i],NULL,worker,(void*)&i);
```

compiler warning message:

```
67:7: warning: passing argument 2 of 'pthread_join' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

means the variable 'work' should be declared, in file global space, not in the thread function, as:

```
void * work;
```

there are other compiler warning messages output, but the above will eliminate them.

I.E. always start with the first compiler message, fix that, then re-compile.  then fix the new first message.

Most of the problems with the syntax of the code could have been avoided by paying attention to the man pages for the system functions that were called in the posted code.

Note: the `crossout()` functions' logic is not correct.  the code needs to start at `k+k`, continue until `k<=n` and step by `k+=k` I.E.

```
for( int k=i+i; k<(n+1); k+=k )
```

the code seems to be trying to implement a   `eratosthenes sieve for prime numbers`  google for the details.

unless your required to use threads, don't, they will just slow things down due to all the context swapping, etc.

this code logic:

```
for (i = 3; i <= n; i++)  
{
    if (i%2 == 0) prime[i] = 0;
    else prime[i] = 1;
}
```

seems to be wrong, for one thing, the array `prime[]` will be initially all 0 because it is in the file global space.  As far as I can tell, that code block is not needed at all.

because the `work` variable will be in the file global space, suggest an array of

```
void* work[ nthreads ];
```

then have the thread function: `worker()`  actually use the passed parameter to select which of the entries in the array to be updating.

Comment: "always exit the worker() function by: pthread_exit( &work );" is plain bullshit. Firstly, returning is perfectly fine. Secondly, returning the address of a local variable is just asking for trouble. Just `return NULL` if you don't have a reason for doing something different.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt,   If you were to read the documentation about threads, rather than resorting to profanity, you would notice that exiting a thread via return or exit() causes `pthread_exit()` to be called.  so to keep things clear, especially to the C programming students, it is best to advocate a proper/graceful exit from the thread.  That proper/graceful exit is via calling `pthread_exit()`

Comment: Let's see... 1. Calling something names (e.g. "profanity") doesn't address its content but only its form, so it isn't really an argument. 2. I said using return is "perfectly fine", while you say that returning will invoke `pthread_exit()` anyway. So, you don't even disagree on a technical base but only on a stylistic one, which you advocate with name calling ("proper", "graceful") yourself. 3. You still advocate returning pointers to locals. That is a dangerous habit for the C programming students and anything but "graceful". Summary: I still consider parts of what you wrote bullshit.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt,  Sorry, I did not advocate returning a pointer to a local,  I do strongly advocate making use of memory allocation (like malloc()) and returning the pointer returned from malloc().   And there you are using profanity again. One is bad, twice is pitiful and the third time, well you can guess about the third time

Comment: Your answer contains code that passes the address of a local object to `pthread_exit()`, which is equivalent to returning a local even though it's not as obvious as using `return`. How about you fix that?

Comment: as I stated in one of my comments to the original question: *the proper way to return from a thread is: pthread_exit( &status ); Note: the status variable should be in the file global space, not the thread stack.*

Comment: The variable `work` in the question is local to the thread function, even though it requires careful reading to notice. Now, let me quote you: "`pthread_exit(&work)`". In this combination, it is just asking for trouble. Why don't you just fix what you wrote? Or are you unable to understand why that is wrong? BTW: Making `work` global, you wouldn't need its address to make it available to other parts of the code. However, while it  removes the problem with dangling pointers, it also introduces other issues as globals always do and possibly even more when shared between threads.